# Drawing cards from $2$ standard decks ($104$ cards)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

If I draw $13$ cards from a deck of $52$ cards, the likelihood of getting a straight of hearts from A to K is:

$$P_{52}=\frac{1}{\binom{52}{13}}\tag{1}$$

because there's only one way to arrange a straight of 13 cards of the same suit, and all the possible draws are $\binom{52}{13}$.

My question is: what's the likelihood of the same event but with **two** decks of cards? My guess is:

$$P_{104}=\frac{2^{13}}{\binom{104}{13}}\tag{2}$$

$\binom{104}{13}$ because now we're drawing $13$ cards from a deck of 104, and $2^{13}$ to account for the fact that each card of the straight could either come from the first deck or the second and all the possible combinations are $2^{13}$.

Is my math righ? Because I'm a bit surprised to find that $P_{104}<P_{52}$ and by a factor of more than $2$. Thanks!

Comment: Well, getting all hearts and getting only hearts, one of each rank are different. So if you want just only hearts, there are quite a few more.

Comment: I agree with your Math.

Comment: Only hearts is $$\dfrac{\binom{26}{13}}{\binom{104}{13}}$$ which is about $1269$ times as likely as a straight heart draw.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, and the original straight hearts draw could have been written $P_{52}=\frac{13 \choose 13}{52 \choose 13}$ to  make the double-deck probability more obvious. The error in the question is that $\frac{2^{13}}{\binom{104}{13}}$ is the probability that you have all $13$ distinct hearts values in the double-deck draw, but there are many other possibilities for the values while still having all hearts

Comment: Sorry I meant drawing a straight of hearts from A to K. I'll edit my question to fix it

Comment: Imagine you are very lucky. You took 13cards in 104, you look at them, the first is a heart, the 2nd also ... the 12th also, and there is no duplicate. Now you will look at the last one. The probability that the last one is the magic missing Queen of Heart is 2/92.  When you do  same experience with 52 cards, if you arrive at same step, the probability that the 13th card is the magic Queen of hearts is 1/40. 1/40 compare to 1/46 : it is more difficult to win when you have 104 cards.